# How to get absolute previous url in event receiver?

Tags: event-receivers, event-handlers, events, remote-event-receiver

I have a root site list which I am displaying on several sub-sites using CQWP based on a custom filter and entering the list values from sub-sites itself to the root site list.

So I am trying to store the sub-sites url when saving values using default `newform.aspx` on the list column. I tried storing url value using workflow,event receiver but not able to store as required. I can achieve this using custom WebPart but don't want this approach. Using WebPart I get the previous visited URL but in event receiver value is null.

Below is the code for getting URL:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath
```

Any solutions would be helpful here. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To take the parent Web URL you have to use this:

```
   public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
           using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
           {
                using (web = site.OpenWeb(properties.RelativeWebUrl))
                {
                   var parentURL= web.ParentWeb.Url.ToString();
                }
           }
        }
```

Comment: yes this doesn't work in event receiver when i fire it on ItemAdded event

Comment: try this: properties.RelativeWebUrl

Comment: this gives me the current url. but i want the parent one.

Comment: answer edited .

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.ToString() this gives me previous URL right, but in event receiver this returns null.

Comment: web.ParentWeb.Url.ToString() again returns me null. web.Url.ToString() gives me root site value

Comment: try .ServerRelativeUrl

Comment: this again gives me "/" value :(

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: you can loop on the site.AllWebs and get the web that is parent of the current

Comment: not able to get it still.

Answer (score 1):

The root problem is that you need an information of the HTTP context from the inside of an ER (i.e. the `UrlReferrer`). HTTP context information is stored at the thread level... but if you use an asynchronous `ItemAdded` event, you run in a separate thread.

Thus, one option may be to use `ItemAdding` or a synchronous `ItemAdded`.
However, in case an item is added through another mean than the UI (PowerShell, timer job, C# server-side OM...), the HTTP context will still be null...
From a functionnality perspective, what do you intend to do if this is the case? From a technical point of view, you must, at least, test whether `HttpContext.Current` is `null` or not.

Comment: One important thing I omitted: what is the absolute path of the page newform.aspx when opened from the sub-site? If this form comes from the root site, the `UrlReferrer` will be that path... Ruining all your efforts to get the original sub-site URL...

Answer (score 1):

As I known, the `HttpContext.Current` only available on synchronous event like ItemAdding, ItemUpdating and ItemDeleting.
Can you try `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath` on `ItemAdding` ?